# How to concatenate two stored values as one in Selenium Java

Tags: java

So I am fairly new at using Java. But here is the issue I need help with.

I am currently at run time storing a value of a "First Name" field Then storing a value of the "Last Name" field.

I need to make those two value to be stored as a single variable example 
"James Willard" Note must have a space between the two values.

I need this put together like this to insert into a single Signature box.
Currently I have two methods one for each value. Is there a way to put this into one method?

Below is my current methods I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Method to Capture First Name for Signature block on Review and Sign 
Page
public String getFirstName() {
    String FName= FirstName.getAttribute("value");
    System.out.println("FirstName in method"+FName);
    return FName;
}

//Method to Capture Last Name for Signature block on Review and Sign 
Page
public String getLastName() {
    String LName= LastName.getAttribute("value");
    System.out.println("LastName in method"+LName);
    return LName;
}
```

Comment: er...couldn't you just define `FName` and `LName` in one method, and concatenate them with `FName + " " + LName`?

Comment: what about making method named getFullName() and get inside it the two values and just print the two values with a space between them.

Comment: Mingle thanks for the response so I am not familiar  with the correct use of the above you provided. So I made an attempt like this String FName= FirstName.getAttribute("value") + " " + LName=LastName.getAttribute("value"); but the LName errors saying cannot resolve to a variable so I'm not sure how exactly I should write this.

Comment: Fady Thanks for the tip I tried as you said after a little trial and error but I now have it working as you had recommended. I truly thank you folks as I am fairly new at this. I appreciate folks helping us less experienced folks get our feet wet so to speak. Thanks again

Comment: @OrangeDog How is that question even remotely a duplicate of this one?